# How can I print error stack trace in JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, exception, servlets, jstl

I have set my error page like this in web.xml:

```
 <error-page>
  <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
  <location>/errors/error.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
```

Now I would like to print stack trace of error on JSP (of course in development mode only). How can I print stack trace of error on my JSP page? I don't use any frameworks for this application, so only default servlet APIs are available for my program.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

get the parameter from request that is set internally and use it to print and deal with other information like `cause`, `message`

```
<c:set var="exception" value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.error.exception']}"/>
```

and to print stacktrace

```
<!-- Stack trace -->
<jsp:scriptlet>
  exception.printStackTrace(new java.io.PrintWriter(out));
</jsp:scriptlet>
```

---

**See Also**

- [JSPIntro4 - Handling Errors](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro4.html)

Comment: how can we use "<jsp:scriptlet>" ? Its giving compilation (jsp parse) exception

Comment: @gtiwari333 You need to add `<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" isErrorPage="true" %>` in the top to enable this.

Answer (score 21):

The following parameters will be set by the container when request is forwarded to the error page.

- javax.servlet.error.status_code
- javax.servlet.error.exception
- javax.servlet.error.message
- javax.servlet.error.request_uri
- javax.servlet.error.servlet_name
- javax.servlet.error.exception_type

**In your error JSP** do this,

```
<%request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception").printStackTrace(new java.io.PrintWriter(out))%>;
```

**Or Else** If your error page is defined as Error page with Page Directive like,

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" import="java.io.*"%>
```

The ***exception*** scripting variable will be declared in the JSP. You can printing the scripting variable using a scriptlet using,

```
exception.printStackTrace(new java.io.PrintWriter(out));
```

Or,

```
<jsp:scriptlet>
    exception.printStackTrace(response.getWriter())
</jsp:scriptlet>
```

Comment: If using facelets you can do `#{requestScope['javax.servlet.error.status_code']}`.

Answer (score 15):

Using JSP scriptlets is a frowned upon practice since a decade. You'd best [avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) it.

If you're already on EL 2.2 or newer (Tomcat 7+, JBoss AS 6+, WildFly, GlassFish 3+, etc), with new support for method expressions of the form `${instance.method()}`, then you can just use 100% EL for this.

First you need to explicitly flush the JSP writer via [`JspWriter#flush()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspWriter.html#flush--), so that all preceding JSP template output really gets written to the writer of the servlet response:

```xml
${pageContext.out.flush()}
```

Then you can just pass [`ServletResponse#getWriter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter--) to [`Throwable#printStackTrace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace-java.io.PrintWriter-).

```xml
${exception.printStackTrace(pageContext.response.writer)}
```

Complete example:

```xml
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" isErrorPage="true" %>
...
<pre>${pageContext.out.flush()}${exception.printStackTrace(pageContext.response.writer)}</pre>
```

If you're already on EL 3.0 (Tomcat 8+, WildFly, GlassFish 4+, etc), you can even make it a single expression with the new semicolon operator which separates EL statements:

```xml
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" isErrorPage="true" %>
...
<pre>${pageContext.out.flush();exception.printStackTrace(pageContext.response.writer)}</pre>
```

If you can't use `isErrorPage="true"` for some reason (and thus `${exception}` implicit object isn't available), then just substitute with `${requestScope['javax.servlet.error.exception']}`:

```xml
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
...
<pre>${pageContext.out.flush()}${requestScope['javax.servlet.error.exception'].printStackTrace(pageContext.response.writer)}</pre>
```

If you're still not on EL 2.2, then your best bet is creating a custom EL function. Detail can be found in [What is the good approach to forward the exception from servlets to a jsp page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257928/what-is-the-good-approach-to-forward-the-exception-from-servlets-to-a-jsp-page/)

Below is a more complete error page example with more detail:

```xml
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" isErrorPage="true" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
...
<ul>
    <li>Exception: <c:out value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.error.exception']}" /></li>
    <li>Exception type: <c:out value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.error.exception_type']}" /></li>
    <li>Exception message: <c:out value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.error.message']}" /></li>
    <li>Request URI: <c:out value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.error.request_uri']}" /></li>
    <li>Servlet name: <c:out value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.error.servlet_name']}" /></li>
    <li>Status code: <c:out value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.error.status_code']}" /></li>
    <li>Stack trace: <pre>${pageContext.out.flush()}${exception.printStackTrace(pageContext.response.writer)}</pre></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: One issue I have encountered is that sometimes the stack trace will contain lines of JSP. These are getting interpreted as HTML in the browser. Is there a means to escape the stack trace? (Normally I'd use c:out but that does not apply in this case.)

Answer (score 3):

On the error page, just do:

```
<jsp:scriptlet>
    exception.printStackTrace(response.getWriter())
</jsp:scriptlet>
```

Although this begs the question: what is a user going to do with an exception. Why not write the exception to the error log so it is persisted and you can go back to it after a user complains?

Answer (score 3):

Or, to avoid using scriptlets in your jsp, use jstl:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
...

<c:set var="exception" value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.error.exception']}"/>

<c:if test="${exception != null}">
  <h4>${exception}</h4>
  <c:forEach var="stackTraceElem" items="${exception.stackTrace}">
    <c:out value="${stackTraceElem}"/><br/>
  </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

Ideally, scriptlets should be disallowed as a best practice.  Explicitly prevent scriplets in you jsp files via the web.xml configuration:

```
<jsp-config>
  <jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <scripting-invalid>true</scripting-invalid>
  </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Answer (score 2):

Thrown Exception object is available as request attribute with name 'javax.servlet.error.exception'. So, in your JSP, you can write:

```
<% request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception").printStackTrace(new java.io.PrintWriter(out); %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jstl core library

1) Import tablib on top of JSP file

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

2) use  tag

```
<c:catch var="myExceptionObject">
    Code that might throw Exception
</c:catch>

<c:if test="${myExceptionObject} != null">
    There was an exception: ${myExceptionObject.message}
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the error.jsp add the below lines

```
<%Logger log = Logger.getLogger("error_jsp.class");
Exception e = (Exception)request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
log.debug(request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.message"));
e.printStackTrace();
log.debug(e.getStackTrace());%>
```