# how to use error page in jsp with source code

Tags: jsp

in jsp page is `"a.jsp"`,if i use `<%@ page errorpage="b.jsp" %>` directive in `"a.jsp"`,My Question is how to use errorpage in jsp?what are the source code to keep in `"b.jsp"`,Please explain in detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `b.jsp` which is error page should look like this:

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" import="java.io.*"%>

............
............
<!--Write your custom error message>
............
<!--Print your exception if required>
<%exception.printStackTrace(new java.io.PrintWriter(out));%>
```

**References**

- [How can i print Exception in JSP Error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135980/how-can-i-print-error-stack-trace-in-jsp-page/8136065#8136065)