# Why FullAjaxExceptionHandler does not simply perform an ExternalContext#redirect()?

Tags: ajax, jsf, redirect, omnifaces, exceptionhandler

In OmniFaces, the [FullAjaxExceptionHandler](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler), after having found the right error page to use, calls the JSF runtime to build the view and render it instead of the page that includes the AJAX call.

Why this? IMHO it would be simpler to just perform a `ExternalContext#redirect()`? Are there specific reasons to do this?

<sub>*We are writing our own ExceptionHandler based on FullAjaxExceptionHandler and wanted to understand the reason behind this design.*</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary goal of the `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` is to let exceptions during ajax requests to behave **exactly** the same as exceptions during non-ajax requests. The developer must be able to reuse the error pages across both conditions without worrying about the condition while implementing the error pages.

A redirect isn't part of the normal flow during non-ajax requests. The default `<error-page>` mechanism in `web.xml` performs a forward to display the error page, not a redirect. If a redirect was performed, all error page request attributes such as `javax.servlet.error.exception` would get lost and render as `null`. Moreover, normal practice is to place error pages in `/WEB-INF` to prevent endusers from being able to directly access (and bookmark and share) them. A redirect would require them to be publicly accessible, which indicates a major design problem (is the intented target page actually a real error page?).

If you really need to perform a redirect to/from your error page, either homegrow a custom exception handler which explicitly invokes `ExternalContext#redirect()` and doesn't utilize `web.xml` `<error-page>` mechanism, or add a `<meta http-equiv="refresh" ...>` to the HTML head of the error page in question ([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3642969)).

In case you actually intended to redirect to some login page when a `ViewExpiredException` occurs, then you should realize that there's a big difference between the cases of "User is not logged in" and "Session/view is expired". For the former, you should not be catching `ViewExpiredException` at all, but use a simple [servlet filter](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/filters/HttpFilter) which checks if the user is logged in and redirect accordingly, long before the `FacesServlet` is invoked. A normal authentication framework (JAAS, Shiro, Spring Security, etc) also works that way.

#### See also:

- [What is the good approach to forward the exception from servlets to a jsp page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257928/what-is-the-good-approach-to-forward-the-exception-from-servlets-to-a-jsp-page)
- [What is the difference between redirect and navigation/forward and when to use what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277366/what-is-the-difference-between-redirect-and-navigation-forward-and-when-to-use-w)
- [Why use a JSF ExceptionHandlerFactory instead of <error-page> redirection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534187/why-use-a-jsf-exceptionhandlerfactory-instead-of-error-page-redirection/)
- [Check if session exists JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144195/check-if-session-exists-jsf/)
- [Authorization redirect on session expiration does not work on submitting a JSF form, page stays the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580267/authorization-redirect-on-session-expiration-does-not-work-on-submitting-a-jsf-f/)