# Cannot invoke "java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace()" because "exception" is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp, tomcat

I am new to Spring boot, and I've stumbled upon this weird Exception.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace()" because "exception" is null
```

AIM: I'm trying to build a basic spring boot rest client application.

ISSUE: Getting an error that exception is null.
i.e

when my @RequestMapping value is **"employee"** it's working fine,

```
@Controller 
public class EmployeeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "employee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getEmployees()
    {
        //.....some working code...
        return mv;
    }

}
```

but when I change it to **"template/employee"**,

```
@Controller 
public class EmployeeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "template/employee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getEmployees()
    {
        //.....some working code...
        return mv;
    }

}
```

it's throwing the error attached below.
Can anyone figure out and explain
what's causing the issue? Thank You.

**Error**

```
e2020-12-10 13:17:27.497[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m14180[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-    
9090-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/].[jsp]       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m 
Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace()" because                         
"exception" is null
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.error_jsp._jspService(error_jsp.java:115) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper- 
9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core- 
9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilterNestedErrorDispatch(OncePerRequestFilter.java:251) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:171) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1394) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1139) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1078) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:398) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:257) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:179) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]





[2m2020-12-10 13:17:27.499[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m14180[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-9090-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace()" because "exception" is null
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.error_jsp._jspService(error_jsp.java:115) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilterNestedErrorDispatch(OncePerRequestFilter.java:251) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:171) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1394) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1139) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1078) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:398) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:257) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:179) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]





[2m2020-12-10 13:17:27.501[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m14180[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-9090-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]          [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace()" because "exception" is null
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:517) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilterNestedErrorDispatch(OncePerRequestFilter.java:251) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:171) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1394) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1139) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1078) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:398) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:257) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:179) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]





Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace()" because "exception" is null
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.error_jsp._jspService(error_jsp.java:115) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
... 61 common frames omitted
```

Here's my **pom.xml** for reference

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.x</groupId>
<artifactId>hrManagerRestTemplate</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>hrManagerRestTemplate</name>
<description>Assignment for x</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>


<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**error.jsp**

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>  

<h3>Sorry an exception occured!</h3>  

Exception is: <%= exception%>  
Exception is: <%= exception.getStackTrace()%>
```

Comment: It looks like you have defined a JSP named `error.jsp` ... and it has a bug in it.  And that is where the NPE is coming from.  You most likely have another problem as well, but the bug in `error.jsp` is hiding the evidence.

Comment: I've included error.jsp as well. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JSP spec](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jsp-api/blob/master/spec/src/main/asciidoc/ServerPages.adoc#_Implicit_Objects_Available_in_Error_Pages) says this:

> In addition, the exception implicit object can be accessed in an error page, as described in Table JSP.1-7 , “Implicit Objects Available in Error Pages”.

> Table JSP.1-7 Implicit Objects Available in Error Pages

| Variable Name | Type | Semantics & Scope |
| --- | --- | --- |
| exception | java.lang.Throwable | The uncaught Throwable that resulted in the error page being invoked. Page scope. |

Your `error.jsp` page is written on the assumption that there was an (non-null) uncaught exception.  Apparently, this is not necessarily the case<sup>1</sup>.  And when it is not the case (i.e. when the `exception` variable is `null`) evaluating the EL expression `exception.getStackTrace()` is going to throw a `NullPointerException`.

So, if you are going to try to call `exception.getStackTrace()` you need to guard the call with a test for `null`.  In addition, calling `getStackTrace()` gives you a `StackTraceElement[]` which (AFAIK) won't render properly.

To get a properly rendered stacktrace you need something like this:

```
<% if (exception != null) 
<pre>
<%= exception.printStackTrace(new java.io.PrintWriter(out)); %>
</pre> %>
```

But it would be better to avoid using scriplets in your JSPs.  For various
alternatives, see [How can I print error stack trace in JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135980/how-can-i-print-error-stack-trace-in-jsp-page) ... though these don't explicitly deal with cases where the exception is `null`.

---

<sup>1 - One possibility is that something in your webapp is explicitly redirecting to the `error.jsp` page.</sup>